# How to find a line which contains a string without any suffix and prefix in a string?

Tags: python-3.x, string

I tried to find the solution on different platform, but I couldn't able to. So I am here.

I am reading a line in a file which contains a specific string(user Input). But the Problem is, my Code is reading all the lines. For an example.

Here user Input is: "Mon_ErrEntryEspSqPlaus"

Output line: 
 /begin MEASUREMENT Icsp_Dem_Deb_LfEve_Mon_ErrEntryEspSqPlaus

Here Output line string has Suffix with it. Not intended.

Instead of reading just below line:

941 "Mon_ErrEntryEspSqPlaus"

No Suffix and prefix in the above line with user Input string.

Here is the  Code:

```
  import re
def a2l_reader(parameter):
    count = 0;
    count_1 = 0;
    with open("TPT.a2l", errors = 'replace') as myfile:
            for num, line in enumerate(myfile,1):
                if parameter in line:
                    if  re.match(r'sample', line):
                        count += 1
                    else:
                        count_1 += 1
    print(count)
    print(count_1)
```

The Question is how to search for the specific line which contains a specific string without Suffix and prefix. Since I have to use the number associated with that string.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Python offers two different primitive operations based on regular expressions: re.match() checks for a match only at the beginning of the string, while re.search() checks for a match anywhere in the string. So if you use re.search(r'sample', line) it would exactly find the presence of the string anywhere in the line irrespective of the suffix and prefix and i have one more question "parameter in line" what do you check here ?

Comment: @redhatvicky, Parameter in line do the same Task as (r'sample, line) and I need to optimize again for the limited lines which contains only the sample without siffix and prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if parameter in line:
```

you can simply do

```
if parameter == line:
```

and it will only proceed if there is an exact match. The first example (which is the one you have in your code) will match if there are substrings matching your input

Comment: thank you for the resposne, in Operator is correct, I already checked with in and == . == will not do the Task, which I need

Comment: `in` looks for substrings, whereas `==` checks the whole string, which is what you need. If the latter doesn't work on your code then or `parameter` or `line` isn't properly formatted. Can you `print(parameter)` and `print(line)` and show the output?

Answer (score 0):

In that case if you want to match the exact string you can split by spaces and then check contains using in ::

Split by Spaces and the check in list 
if parameter in re.split("( )",line):

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You want to check the presence of parameter in the line i.e You wanted to exactly match the presence of parameter in the line without any prefix or suffix which is basically a whole word match , So we are just trying to split the line using spaces and then trying to find the parameter exist in the list. Am i clear with the required thing or am i missing something ?

Comment: `re.split("( )",line)` should be replaced with `line.split()`. The built-in `split` separates by whitespace by default